# Como llamar los valores en el select dado el id de un usuario

Tags: html, mysql, php7

Tengo una aplicacion en la cual tengo un modulo de novedades MVC organizado de la siguiente manera:

CONTROLADOR
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MODELO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

VISTA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

FORMULARIO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, al momento de ingresar los dos me vota elsiguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es como hago para que dados el campo documento y estudiante me muestre automaticamente los datos que le corresponden a inscripciòn y dados los de inscripciòn muestre automaticamente los demàs sombreados.

Comment: Error de sintaxis... tienes algo mal escrito amigo... en el `ISERT INTO novedad...` ... Por otro lado, el codigo y los errores se deben poner como texto, las imágenes acá son un mal que debemos evitar.

Comment: Gracias. Voy a revisar. Y también a cambiar las imágenes.

Comment: Como apreciación, nunca dejes un mensaje de error de sql en tu frontend, solo dejas vulnerable tu plataforma. Saludos.